# Is this the correct implementation of a MAML model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, supervised-learning, meta-learning

I have used CLIP embeddings of image and text as the input and the output is a label ranging from 0 to 5 (6 way label). I tried to make an implemention of this multimodal 6 way classification using meta learning. I tried using a code which includes MAML (Model Agnostic Meta Learning).
What am I doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

import warnings

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
print(device)

class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = torch.tensor(x, dtype=torch.float32).to(device)
        self.y = torch.tensor(y, dtype=torch.long).to(device)
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.x)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.x[idx], self.y[idx]

class MAML(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim):
        super(MAML, self).__init__()
        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        self.num_samples = 10
        self.epochs = 20
        self.alpha = 0.001  # Adjusted learning rate
        self.beta = 0.001  # Adjusted meta learning rate
        self.theta = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(input_dim, output_dim).to(device))
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        a = torch.matmul(x, self.theta)
        return self.softmax(a)

    def sample_points(self, k, x, y):
        indices = np.random.choice(len(x), k)
        return x[indices], y[indices]

    def train(self, x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val):
        train_dataset = CustomDataset(x_train, y_train)
        train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=self.num_samples, shuffle=True)

        optimizer = optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=self.alpha)

        for e in range(1, self.epochs + 1):
            self.theta_ = []
            for x_batch, y_batch in train_loader:
                x_batch = x_batch.to(device)
                y_batch = y_batch.to(device)

                y_hat = self.forward(x_batch)
                y_batch_encoded = torch.eye(self.output_dim, device=device)[y_batch]
                loss = -torch.mean(y_batch_encoded * torch.log(y_hat + 1e-7))

                optimizer.zero_grad()
                loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()

                self.theta_.append(self.theta.detach().clone())

            meta_gradient = torch.zeros_like(self.theta, dtype=torch.float32).to(device)
            for i in range(self.num_samples):
                x_test, y_test = self.sample_points(10, x_train, y_train)
                x_test = torch.tensor(x_test, dtype=torch.float32).to(device)
                y_pred = self.forward(x_test)
                y_test_encoded = torch.eye(self.output_dim)[y_test].to(device)
                meta_gradient += torch.matmul(x_test.T, (y_pred - y_test_encoded)) / self.num_samples

            self.theta.data -= self.beta * meta_gradient

            with warnings.catch_warnings():
                warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning)
                x_val = torch.tensor(x_val, dtype=torch.float32).to(device).clone().detach().requires_grad_(True)
            y_val_pred = self.forward(x_val)
            val_loss = -torch.mean(torch.eye(self.output_dim, device=device)[y_val] * torch.log(y_val_pred + 1e-7))

    def predict(self, x):
        with torch.no_grad():
            x = torch.tensor(x, dtype=torch.float32).to(device)
            y_pred = self.forward(x)
            _, predictions = torch.max(y_pred, dim=1)
            return predictions.cpu().numpy()

# Load the dataset
data = pd.read_csv('data/text_image_embeddings.csv')
x_text = data['text_embedding'].str.split('\t', expand=True).astype(float).values
x_image = data['image_embedding'].str.split('\t', expand=True).astype(float).values
x = np.concatenate((x_text, x_image), axis=1)
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
y = label_encoder.fit_transform(data['label'])
len(data)
num_labels = len(label_encoder.classes_)
print(num_labels)
models = []
accuracies = []
for i in range(num_labels):
    # Divide data into train and validation for the current label/task
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.8, stratify=y, random_state=i)
    
    # Create the CustomDataset for the current label/task
    train_dataset = CustomDataset(x_train, y_train)
    train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=10, shuffle=True)
    
    # Create the MAML model for the current label/task
    model = MAML(input_dim=x.shape[1], output_dim=num_labels).to(device)
    models.append(model)
    
    # Train the model for the current label/task
    model.train(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test)
    
    # Calculate accuracy on the validation dataset for the current label/task
    val_predictions = model.predict(x_test)
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, val_predictions)
    accuracies.append(accuracy)

# Print the accuracies for each label/task
for label, accuracy in zip(label_encoder.classes_, accuracies):
    print(f"Label: {label}, Accuracy: {accuracy:.4f}")
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be mostly correct but something is wrong with respect to the way the accuracy is calculated.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

# ... (the rest of the code remains unchanged) ...

# Initialize the number of outer and inner folds for nested cross-validation
num_outer_folds = 5
num_inner_folds = 3

# Perform nested cross-validation for each label
for label_idx, label in enumerate(label_encoder.classes_):
    # Get the indices of data points corresponding to the current label
    label_indices = np.where(y == label_idx)[0]

    # Outer loop: Perform stratified k-fold cross-validation for evaluation
    outer_kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=num_outer_folds, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

    # List to store accuracy for each outer fold
    outer_fold_accuracies = []

    for outer_fold_idx, (train_outer_idx, test_outer_idx) in enumerate(outer_kfold.split(label_indices, y[label_indices])):
        # Split data into outer training and test sets for the current outer fold
        x_train_outer, x_test_outer = x[label_indices[train_outer_idx]], x[label_indices[test_outer_idx]]
        y_train_outer, y_test_outer = y[label_indices[train_outer_idx]], y[label_indices[test_outer_idx]]

        # Inner loop: Perform stratified k-fold cross-validation for model selection
        inner_kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=num_inner_folds, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

        # List to store accuracy for each inner fold
        inner_fold_accuracies = []

        for inner_fold_idx, (train_inner_idx, val_inner_idx) in enumerate(inner_kfold.split(x_train_outer, y_train_outer)):
            # Split data into inner training and validation sets for the current inner fold
            x_train_inner, x_val_inner = x_train_outer[train_inner_idx], x_train_outer[val_inner_idx]
            y_train_inner, y_val_inner = y_train_outer[train_inner_idx], y_train_outer[val_inner_idx]

            # Create the CustomDataset for the current inner fold
            train_dataset = CustomDataset(x_train_inner, y_train_inner)
            train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=10, shuffle=True)

            # Create the MAML model for the current label
            model = MAML(input_dim=x.shape[1], output_dim=num_labels).to(device)

            # Train the model for the current inner fold
            model.train(x_train_inner, y_train_inner, x_val_inner, y_val_inner)

            # Calculate accuracy on the validation dataset for the current inner fold
            val_predictions = model.predict(x_val_inner)
            accuracy = accuracy_score(y_val_inner, val_predictions)
            inner_fold_accuracies.append(accuracy)

        # Calculate and report average accuracy for the current label across all inner folds
        avg_inner_accuracy = np.mean(inner_fold_accuracies)

        # Store the average accuracy for the current outer fold
        outer_fold_accuracies.append(avg_inner_accuracy)

    # Calculate and report average accuracy for the current label across all outer folds
    avg_accuracy = np.mean(outer_fold_accuracies)
    print(f"Label: {label}, Average Accuracy: {avg_accuracy:.4f}")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your answer is a bit unclear, but likely problematic either way I interpret it -- Are you saying that you have tracked down the issue to somewhere in the code you posted, but you don't know what the exact problem is? If that's the case, then we consider this "Not an answer", as it doesn't attempt to *solve* the problem.  You can comment on others' posts when you gain some more reputation.

Comment: Or perhaps you are saying that the code you provided solves the problem, but you don't know why.  In that case, it would seem that you obtained the updated code that you posted from some other source such as an AI tool like ChatGPT.  If this is the case, I need to let you know that [posting of AI-generated content is not permitted on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831).

Comment: Either way, please update (or delete, if it is AI-assistance) your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).